# qtoolbar button mouse clicking not working

Tags: qt

This is weird.  The toolbar on the left side in only clickable at the very corner.
But if I move the button position to the right of the other buttons it is clickable.  It seems like its only that what ever button is first on the left side.

This image shows that I cant click on the button when I mouse over it.

[image]

This image shows that I can click on it on the lower corner of the image only.

[image]

**Update 1**

OK this is weird.  I added a menu on top just to see using the Designer and now my toolbar works.

But I also noticed that my menu item on the left doesnt

[image]

But If I click on any menu item to the right that I can click and move to the left, then I can click on the menu item that I wasnt able to originally

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

I was able to resolve it by calling raise() on the toolbar fixed the issue.

Comment: How did you create the Button? Some code please!

Comment: I just use the GUI editor to add the buttons and in my code I assigned a QIcon and tooltip like this:

this->ui->actionGeneralSettings->setIcon(QIcon("://toolbar/Images/Toolbar/settings.png"));

this->ui->actionGeneralSettings->setToolTip(QString("General Settings"));

Comment: Ah okay, so you are using an action... Well then it should work. Without some more code it's impossible to determine where this error comes from